# Do comets and meteors attract artificial satellites while passing by?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, estimation, satellites, meteors, comets

What will be effect on artificial satellites when comets or meteors come close or pass by?

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational effect is certainly negligible. Usual comets passing by do so at distances too large and aren't massive enough; meteors crossing Earth also have masses too little. Not even the moon has a noticeable effect on trajectories of satellites.

Comment: absolutely not true.

Comment: @niels You seem to be talking about spacecraft sent to comets. To me it appears the questions is about comets passing by Earth and meteors reaching the atmosphere and their effects on satellites of Earth.

Comment: you are probably right. will delete. -NN

Comment: sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do, but the effect is slight unless the satellite is very close to the comet or meteoroid.

Gravity scales as mass divided by [distance squared].
The Apollo command module orbited the moon about $2000$ km from the moon's center. 
The moon is about $10^{23}$ kg while a comet might be about $10^{15}$ kg.
So that is about a $10^8$ greater mass, so a satellite would have to come 10,000 times closer to the comet - or within just a fraction of a kilometer.

Space is pretty empty, so that is not too likely.